# Check that f is not Lipschitz in the initial condition

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

I want to prove that the problem below is not Lipschitz at $t = 0$.

$
\left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  \frac{d}{dt}y(t) = 3(y(t))^\frac{2}{3}, t \geqslant 0\\
                  y(0) = 0
                \end{array}
              \right.
$

I managed to develop the part below, but I don't know how to continue.

$||f(t,y_1) - f(t,y_2)|| = ||3(y_1(t))^\frac{2}{3} - 3(y_2(t))^\frac{2}{3}|| = 3||(y_1(t))^\frac{2}{3} - (y_2(t))^\frac{2}{3}||$.

In my lay knowledge, I would have to do the condition $\leq$ but I don't know how to elaborate it. Incidentally, in that case, would I be able to prove that it is not Lipschitz for any $t > 0$?

Thank you!

Comment: One way is to note that $y(t)=0$ (identically) is one solution, and $y(t)=t^3u(t)$ where $u(t)$ is the Heaviside step is another solution. Since there are two solutions, the function cannot be Lipschitz; it would violate the Picard-Lindelof theorem. To answer more explicitly: use the mean value theorem: $f’(y)$ blows up at $y=0$ so $f(y)$ cannot be Lipschitz.

Comment: This is very smart. But I would have some way of proving using just the inequality of Lipschitz?

Comment: The mean value theorem strategy proves it directly from the Lipschitz inequality: take $0 < y_1 < y_2 < \delta$. Then there is $c$ between $y_1$ and $y_2$ such that $\lvert f(y_1) - f(y_2)\rvert = \lvert f’(c) \rvert \lvert y_1-y_2\rvert$. For any fixed $K>0$, you can choose $\delta$ small enough that $f’(c) > K$ and so $\lvert f(y_1)-f(y_2)\rvert > K\lvert y_1-y_2\rvert.$ This shows $K$ is not a Lipschitz constant for $f$.

Comment: So, $ |f(y_1)−f(y_2)|=|f′(c)||y_1−y_2| \rightarrow |(3(y_1(t))^\frac{2}{3})−(3(y_2(t))^\frac{2}{3})|=|(2(y(t))^\frac{-1}{3})||y_1−y_2|$. But I didn't understand how $f′(c)$ will be bigger than a $K$.Can you explain me?